# Remove added symbol from mapbox_gl flutter

Tags: flutter, mapbox, marker, mapbox-gl

I want to remove added symbol from map and **I'm using mapbox
and mapbox_gl latest package.**

```
await controller.addSymbol(
        SymbolOptions(
          draggable: true,
          geometry: LatLng(selection.geometry['coordinates'][1],
              selection.geometry['coordinates'][0]),
          iconSize: 0.1,
          iconImage: "square",
        ),
      );
```

Here, icon is added to map. but i cant able to remove it. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the reference to the symbol. This allows you to interact later e.g.:

```
var symbol = await controller.addSymbol(
    SymbolOptions(
        draggable: true,
        geometry: LatLng(selection.geometry['coordinates'][1],
            selection.geometry['coordinates'][0]),
        iconSize: 0.1,
        iconImage: "square",
    ),
);
```

You then can do:

```
await controller.removeSymbol(symbol);
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly. Before that i was using   await controller.clearSymbols();
which removes all icons And mapping again which i don't want to remove.
Thanks your solution helps.